# Why are server authentication mode options are greyed out in Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I tried to search for the solution but couldn't find any. Please help me understand why the server authentication  mode options are greyed out in Sql server 2005. I want to allow SQL Server login mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that your windows user may not be privileged to change the authentication mode. Your local user isn't assigned to the windows group "Administrators" or has the needed permissions for this.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.bigresource.com/MS_SQL-SQL-Server-Express-authentication-mode-greyed-out-93T2w7KL.html) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/780a2ffe-eadb-4b39-83d8-10faa9313f35/sql-server-express-authentication-mode-greyed-out?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade).

Comment: Also have a look on here http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/recognize-authentication-mode-in-sql-server/